# Accessing Android Views in Java files

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've designed a `RelativeLayout` with children elements such as `TextView` and `ImageView`. What I want to do is to create a `RelativeLayout` object from my created `RelativeLayout` in XML, that way I can access to its children elements and modify them (change image from `ImageView` and change the text from `TextView`). How can I do this? It would be kind of like this.

```
RelativeLayout lay = new "myrelativelayout";
ImageView img = lay.children[0];
TextView txt = lay.children[1];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_id"
         ...>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_id"
        .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity onCreate:

```
RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
```

To change children use:

```
TextView child = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
child.setText(text);
```

or:

```
View child = lay.getChildAt(i);
```

Comment: Good answer. I had to use "inflater" because my RelativeLayout is in "layout" folder instead of "drawable" one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access the layout we use the `findViewById` method. Therefore to change the image in the `ImageView` you do not really need access to the `RelativeLayout`.

The way we access any element through its id is as follows:

```
View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.view_id);
```

where `view_id` is the ID of the view.

To access the `RelativeLayout`, therefore, the piece of code would be:

```
RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
```

But if you only want to change the text in the `TextView`, you really don't need the above code. It is sufficient if you do a similar access for the `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview);
textView.setText(text);
```

A general method of accessing any resource can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).